# Parsing data with unknown JSON nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to convert some JSON into a javascript arrays, however, the date is used a key as well as an attribute in the node.  I wanted to use a map function to extract the dates, however, I have the extra date key which I don't know ahead of time.  Do I have to loop through the keys and parse out the data or is there a clever way I can use javascript functions like map to do it?

```
    var label_Dates = data.map(({date}) => date);
    var label_Data = data.map(({totalAssets}) => totalAssets);


    JSON data:

    2020-03-31: {...}
        date: "2020-03-31"
        totalAssets: "300280000000.00"
    2019-12-31: {...}
        date: "2019-12-31"
        totalAssets: "306928000000.00"
    2019-09-30: {...}
    2019-06-30: {...}
    2019-03-31: {...}
    2018-12-31: {...}
    2018-09-30: {...}
    2018-06-30: {...}
    2018-03-31: {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows you have to put all of the values of a JSON object into an array:

```
var json = {"date1":"aa","date2":"cc"};

const arr = Object.values(json);

console.log(arr);
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'cc']
```

Comment: That worked :)  

Any idea how to make "totalAssets" a variable so that I can get other fields with: 
var label_Data = data.map(({totalAssets}) => totalAssets);


2020-06-30: {...}
date: "2020-06-30"
filing_date: null
currency_symbol: "USD"
totalAssets: "54901000000.00"
intangibleAssets: "2852000000.00"
earningAssets: null
otherCurrentAssets: null
totalLiab: "46384000000.00"
totalStockholderEquity: "8517000000.00"
deferredLongTermLiab: null
otherCurrentLiab: "558000000.00"
commonStock: "3000000.00"